# Does every Aronszajn tree has a Suslin or a Special subtree?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

**Question:** Does every $\omega_1$-Aronszajn tree contains a Suslin sub-tree or a special Aronszajn sub-tree?

Recall that Suslin trees are $\omega_1$-trees (trees of height $\omega_1$, and countable width) that have only countable anti-chains. Special Aronszajn trees are $\omega_1$-trees that can be represented as a countable union of anti-chains. Aronszajn trees are $\omega_1$-trees without branches.

Every sub-tree of a special Aronszajn tree with height $\omega_1$ is special, and therefore - not Suslin. Similarly, every subtree of a Suslin tree is Suslin so it's not special.

So, my question is if those are the only possibilities or that (consistently) there are other kinds of Aronszajn trees in which every sub-tree is not a Suslin tree and not a special Aronszajn tree.

Note that under $MA$, for example, every Aronszajn tree is special, so it is consistent that the answer is (trivially) positive.

**Edit:** In this question, a sub-tree is a subset with the restricted order, namely if $\langle T,<_T\rangle$ is a tree, then for every $X\subset T$, $\langle X, <_T \cap (X\times X)\rangle$ is a subtree (usually not an $\omega_1$-tree by itself).

**Sub Question:** Is it consistent that there is an $\omega_1$-tree that has no special sub tree but it is not Suslin?

Mohammad Golshani asked this question in the comments. Maybe a solution for the sub-question will lead to an answer for the main question.

Comment: The following papers may be useful: 1)  Hanazawa, Masazumi On a classification of Aronszajn trees. Tsukuba J. Math. 4 (1980), no. 2, 257–268. 2)  Hanazawa, Masazumi On a classification of Aronszajn trees. II. Tsukuba J. Math. 5 (1981), no. 1, 117–132. 3)  Hanazawa, Masazumi Various kinds of Aronszajn tree with no subtree of a different kind. Logic Symposia, Hakone 1979, 1980 (Hakone, 1979/1980), pp. 1–21, Lecture Notes in Math., 891, Springer, Berlin-New York, 1981.

Comment: All we need is a non-Suslin Arnoszajn tree? then using iterated forcing we can remove all of them.

Comment: Such a tree can not be $\mathbb{R}-$embeddable, since otherwise it contains a special Aronszajn subtree, namely the subset consisting of successor levels of the tree.

Comment: @Eran I want more than just some non-Suslin Aronszajn trees (which always exist - just take some special Aronszajn tree), I want trees that don't have any Suslin **or** special sub-trees.

Comment: @MohammadGolshani these papers look promising. I'll take a look at them.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'subtree' here?

Comment: I think more clarification of 'subtree' is needed here.  If you count every subset of a tree as a subtree, then given any non-Suslin tree $T$, find some uncountable antichain $A$; isn't it special?

Comment: You might also want to look at Chapter IX of Shelah's "Proper and Improper Forcing".

Comment: @Paul: Funny you should say that. He carry a physical copy of that in his backpack. :-P

Comment: @PaulMcKenney : a subtree that contains a single uncountable antichain won't be a special Aronszajn tree since it won't be an $\omega_1$-tree (it has height $1$ and width $\omega_1$). In the definition of special Aronszajn tree I demanded that the tree is $\omega_1$-tree.

Comment: @YairHayut : I see: being a subtree and an $\omega_1$-tree is much more restrictive than I thought.

Comment: @YairHayut Do you know an example of an Aronszajn tree without any special subtrees?

Comment: @Mohammad: Do you mean other than a Suslin tree?

Comment: I don't know any examples for trees that have no special subtree and they are not Suslin.

Comment: @Mohammad : it seems that examples 12 and 13 from the second paper you referenced answer the question.

Comment: @Eran : can you explain further? I don't understand why those trees don't have a Aronszajn subtree.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0312445.pdf - This paper seems to be have something quite close to what you want: Consistently, there is no Souslin tree and there is an Aronszajn tree such that every subtree obtained by taking _all_ nodes at unbounded many levels is not special.

Comment: @Ashutosh: Thanks. The fact that it was only published recently might indicate that this problem is harder than I thought.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is consistent that the answer is no. The following is proved in Beaodouin's thesis ``[On uncountable trees and linear orders](http://libarchive.dartmouth.edu/cdm/ref/collection/dcdis/id/149265)'', as Theorem 1.10:

> **Theorem.** Assume $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\kappa$ and $\Diamond(E)$ holds, where
>   $E \subseteq \{\alpha < \kappa^+: cf(\alpha)=\kappa    \}$.Then there is a normal $\kappa^+$-Aronszajn tree which has no special or Souslin subtree of size $\kappa^+.$

I may mention that the theorem is not stated as above in the paper, but looking at the proof, it is clear that the above result is in fact proved. It is also mentioned in the paper that the case $\kappa=\omega$ has discovered by Hanazawa too.